# XBee-Pro 900HP Communication in API Mode

Tags: arduino, xbee, teensy

I've been been trying to get an Xbee-Pro 900HP to communicate with another Xbee, but it doesn't seem to work. I've confirmed that the xbees are set up correctly as they can communicate remotely over XCTU, so it is either my code or my setup. I've gotten the setup checked by people I trust, so that really only leaves the code. Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong? (Teensy 4.0, API 2 Mode)

```
#include <Printers.h>
#include <XBee.h>

//int test1 = 5;

XBee xbee = XBee();
//SoftwareSerial sserial(1,0);

//String altstring = String(alt);
uint8_t test1[]= {'H', 'i'}; 
//Tx16Request tx = Tx16Request(0xFFFE, packet, sizeof(packet));

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(9600); //debug
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  Serial2.begin(9600);
  xbee.setSerial(Serial1);

  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Setup Complete\n");
  Serial.println("Check Reciving radio Console");
  
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("test");
  
  XBeeAddress64 addr64 = XBeeAddress64(0x13A200, 0x41DDEE70);
  Tx64Request tx = Tx64Request(addr64, test1, sizeof(test1));

  xbee.send(tx);
  delay(5000);

}
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean?

Comment: Just that when I upload the code to the teensy, the xbee does turn on and can be connected to, but it does not send any messages